# Storing from a file into an array or avariable PHP

Tags: php, mysql, file, csv, gmail

So I have a CSV generated from gmail exporting contacts and I need to be able to manage them. I need to get some of the values and pass them to MySQL database, I know how to do that once I got the data but I don't know how to store the data to do that. Hope I explained it correctly, and please keep in mind that I'm a totally noob programmer.

That's an example of the file:

```
Name,Given Name,Additional Name,Family Name,Yomi Name,Given Name Yomi,Additional Name Yomi,Family Name Yomi,Name Prefix,Name Suffix,Initials,Nickname,Short Name,Maiden Name,Birthday,Gender,Location,Billing Information,Directory Server,Mileage,Occupation,Hobby,Sensitivity,Priority,Subject,Notes,Group Membership,E-mail 1 - Type,E-mail 1 - Value,E-mail 2 - Type,E-mail 2 - Value,Phone 1 - Type,Phone 1 - Value,Phone 2 - Type,Phone 2 - Value,Phone 3 - Type,Phone 3 - Value
Firstname Lastname1 Lastname2,Firstname,Lastname1,Lastname2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,GROUP ::: * My Contacts,* Work,EMAIL@hotmail.com,,,Mobile,679999999,,,,
Firstname Lastname1 Lastname2,Firstname,Lastname1,Lastname2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,GROUP ::: * My Contacts,* Work,email@gmail.com,,,Mobile,679999999,,,,
```

Comment: Starting point: [fgetcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)

Comment: So, you want to read from csv file and store them to database. Right ?

Comment: Yeah, but once I managed to get  the data into a string or something i can manage by myself to get it in the db. Just need help reading the data from the file in PHP.

Comment: Please provide a code example of what you are using. Add any errors you get when you run your code.

Comment: `<?php
$data = fopen("google.csv", "r");
?>`    That's my code right now, I know it's nothing but I don't know how to manage the file after opening it I'm a total noob in PHP, and programming overall.

Comment: To be more specific I'd like to get "Firstname" "Lastname1" "Lastname2" "GROUP" "email" "phone number". In a way that later I'd be able to insert that data into the db.

Answer (score 0):

i wont give you the answer, but this code will help you

```
    $file = fopen("google.csv","r")or die("file dont exist");
    while (!feof($file )){
    $data= fgetcsv($file,4096,",");

//insert to db 
    $loadsql = "INSERT INTO temporal_table(id,state,etc) VALUES ('$data[0]','$data[1]','etc');";
    //where  $data[n] is 1 data in a line of your csv file, in this case $data[0] is Name
    mysql_query($loadsql) or die(mysql_error()); 

    }
    fclose($file );
```

Comment: I already did it in abad way that took me too much time but still appreciate your comment, I understand now the use of fgetcsv() o thank you.